# How to call an action after click() in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an image and some other actions after I click a certain DOM element, but I want to load them AFTER the clicking action finished.

Here is a code example:

```
 $("#message_link").click(function(){
   if (some_conditions...){
       $("#header").append("<div><img alt=\"Loader\"src=\"/images/ajax-loader.gif\"  /></div>");
   }
 });
```

The problem is that the if condition executes before the click action have finished(Or at least that is my impression). I need that the If condition executes after the click action has finished. Can some one please tell me a solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the above code to see if it does what you want it to do?

Comment: A click is pretty fast. Is the click triggering something else that needs to finish before you do this?

Comment: In fact that 'click' action _is_ the action for the click

Comment: Yes I have tried it, the problem is that the "#selector" is a submit button in a jquery validation form, so the errors appear after the click happens, and I want to load the image just when there are no errors in the form, so it looks like a loading image telling that "We are processing your form please be patient".

Comment: set a timeout to execute a certain time later

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you are looking for the `mouseup` event, rather than the `click` event:

```
$("#message_link").mouseup(function() {
    //Do stuff here
});
```

The `mouseup` event fires when the mouse button is released, and does not take into account whether the mouse button was pressed on that element, whereas `click` takes into account both `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

However, `click` should work fine, because it won't actually fire until the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 61):

`setTimeout` may help out here

```
$("#message_link").click(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
       if (some_conditions...){
           $("#header").append("<div><img alt=\"Loader\"src=\"/images/ajax-loader.gif\"  /></div>");
       }
   }, 100);
});
```

That will cause the div to be appended ~100ms after the click event occurs, if some_conditions are met.

Comment: This is right solution in some circumtences like in form submitting.

Comment: it's a hack but the only way i could find

Comment: Worked for me. I needed this for after the hash in the URL gets changed. Click was too fast and mouseup didn't fire right. Thanks!

Comment: Yay, race conditions... love those...

Answer (score 5):

you can write events on elements like chain,

```
$(element).on('click',function(){
   //action on click
}).on('mouseup',function(){
   //action on mouseup (just before click event)
});
```

i've used it for removing cart items. same object, doing some action, after another action

Comment: Being able to chain calls to `.on` like that has nothing to do with `click` and `mouseup` happening in that sequence one after the other. Both event listeners are just attached to `$(element)`